# How can I access this JSON data in flutter?

Tags: json, firebase, flutter

I do know how to access json data. But this file is available to me not online but locally. So should I upload this JSON data file to firebase storage and access it from there?  And one more thing, that how would I access data from this Json. Its formate is :

```
 [
    [
     {
      "nos": 0,
       "name": "nnnnnnnasdfnnn",
       "unique_id": "adfadfd",
       "reg_details": [
                        {
                          "registered_with": "adfasdfasdf"
                          },
                          {
                          "type_of_ngo": "zzzzzzzz"
                          },
                          {
                          "registration_no": "zzzzzxxx"
                          },
```

Any example to access this kind of json data would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flutter/flutter_accessing_rest_api.htm  check this

Comment: Could you add the full JSON data? Generally you can access JSON data like this: jsonObject["identifier"];